# How large of a percentage of the Afghan population did NATO and ANSF actually have control over?

Tags: nato, afghanistan

I don't see this being discussed much. [According to the CIA](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/field/urbanization/), only 26% of the Afghan population live in cities. I've been reading that NATO and the Afghan National Security Forces only focused on controlling major cities in Afghanistan, which doesn't make much sense considering this number. That means, they, at most, could protect/control 8 out of 32 million Afghans.

I understand that they couldn't control villages since they are often hard to reach, but I don't understand how NATO thought they would succeed controlling only major population centers. That makes sense in a highly urbanized country, but not a country like Afghanistan.

Some villages are probably close to cities, and thus, NATO and ANSF may have presided over more than 8 millions. Do we have any numbers over how much of Afghanistan NATO and ANSF actually controlled, in terms of population?

Comment: NATO definitely tried to project power in villages during the "surge" from years ago, when troop its levels reached 150,00 or so. I'm guessing it just wasn't politically sustainable in the member countries (in the US chiefly). So driving the Taliban to a stalemate was the post-2015 "plan B".

Comment: Afghan people are Afghans.  Afghani is a unit of money.  On a side note, and as someone who served in Afghanistan in an intelligence role, I have voted to close this question.  It is far too broad and counter-insurgency and nation-building doctrines of of dozens on countries delivered via hundreds of organisations is beyond the ability of any stack exchange answer.  That is before we clarify the context of 'control' and also without opening up a discussion into the ANSF, ANA, ANP and other Afghan security infrastructure.  It is also false that NATO attempted to only control major cities.

Comment: @Venture2099 There's a question on this very site asking what the US and NATO has been doing in Afghanistan for the past 20 years which is much broader than this one. Obviously, it doesn't have a complete answer, but the question is up. It's getting answers that can probably be satisfactory. 
This question doesn't really ask about nation-building doctrines and counterinsurgency. The question is the final sentence and in the title. The rest is just context.

Comment: Define control.  Those other questions should be closed as well.  This is politics SE not warfare SE.  Your question is undermined by this statement - "but I don't understand how NATO thought they would succeed controlling only major population centers. That makes sense in a highly urbanized country, but not a country like Afghanistan.".  That makes your question suspect and clearly a segue into a debate about your perception of NATO failures.

Comment: For a start, it was not a specific NATO aim to control population centres and there was very little unified policy across Afghanistan.  Each member country had different approaches, strategies, resources and rules of engagement.  For instance, in Helmand the UK Forces placed far greater emphasis on control of the Green Zone, major transport routes and security of the Kajaki Dam.  That is before we get into tribal dynamics, warlord feudalism and rural social dynamics.   Your question is far too broad and open to 2 or 3 volumes of analysis.

Comment: Control of population centres is crucial to supporting peaceful elections and ensuring supplies into a geographical territory can be maintained.  Whilst a significant amount of the population may live rurally, without adequate support to a population centre military defeat is assured and assured quickly.  So, I have voted to close your question because it is a question based on a lack of knowledge of military tactics, strategy, Afghan cultural and geographic knowledge and an understanding of how NATO operated. To explain those things is an entire syllabus of learning.

Comment: I would add, that whilst my comments might seem harsh, you would do much better to visit the Small Wars Council, RAND or the Jamestown Blog for much more informed analysis than you get here. The majority of answers here are likely to be written by people wholly unqualified to do so with very little expertise or experience and based on their reading of equally misguided civilian analysis from the news.

Comment: When? It varied wildly over 20 years.

Comment: @ohwilleke well,  considering the current situation has more to do with mission creep rather than the original mission, I would complety exclude the first number of years. Afterwards, I am not completely sure. The past few years may be the most relevant.

Comment: current situation has more to do with mission creep - does it?  In what way?  NATO actions in Afghanistan were started in 2001 but the British Forces deployed to Helmand until 2006.  Why would the past few years be the most relevant?  Do you think we only started nation-building in the last few years?

Comment: @Venture2099 Well, the last sentence there wasn't phrased the way I wanted to (since I didn't recall the exact year I was thinking of). I meant more that the period from 2013-14 onward may be the most relevant since that's when the US government expressed wanting to withdraw all of its troops and Taliban started making a resurgence.
My mission creep comment had to do with the fact that nation building was not exactly a part of the original mission.